# Django autocomplete based on drop down selection

Tags: jquery, django, forms

I am storing the autocompletion data in SomeObject objects and successfully use the following to autocomplete with a filter based on current user:

views.py

```
def get_autocompletion_list(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')

        results = []
        if len(q) > 0:
            my_words = SomeObject.objects.filter(owner=request.user.id)
            words = my_words.filter(word__startswith=q)
            for w in words:
                results.append(w.word)

        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = ''

    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

template:

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="">
    {% csrf_token %}

     {{form.category}}
</form>

<input id="searching">
```

scripts:

```
  $("#category_id").change(function () {

    console.log("selected category")
    console.log($(category_id).val())

  });


$(function() {

     $("#searching").autocomplete({
       source: "/api/get_autocompletion_list/",
       select: function (event, ui) {
         AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
       },
       minLength: 1,
     });
});
```

Now I want to filter the autocompletion based on the selection of form.category drop down, I am able to get the current selection in the form, but how would I send it to the view where I can do the filtering?

Comment: Do you know django-select2? May be is useful for you. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send the data over to django by adding the id for the currently selected category to the url used for the autocompletion.

```
//when value is changed in the dropdown
$("#category_id").change(function () {
  setAutocompletion()
});

//change the url based on the selected drop down value
function setAutocompletion(){
    $("#searching").autocomplete({
      source: "/api/get_autocompletion_list/" + getSelectedValue(),
      select: function (event, ui) {
        AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
      },
      minLength: 1,
    });
}

function getSelectedValue() {
    var s = $(id_kategori).val()
    return String(s)
}

function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui) {
     var selectedObj = ui.item;
}
```